# readPreference secondaryPreferred is not only reading from Secondary nodes

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 mongo instance runing on AWS, 1 Primary and 2 Secondary. We want all read queries to go to secondary nodes, so we are using these config options when creating the mongoose connection:

```json
options = {
    db: {
       readPreference: 'secondaryPreferred',
       native_parser: true
    },
    replset: {
        strategy: 'ping',
        auto_reconnect: false,
    }
};
mongoose.connect(databaseUrl, options);
```

**Problem**: With these settings, read queries go to both *Primary* and *Secondary* nodes, while 2 secondaries nodes are running.

When we use `readPreference: 'secondary'`, it's working as we expect: All read queries go only to the secondaries.

Please help me to explain this because with the mongo docs mention:

> **secondaryPreferred**: In most situations, operations read from secondary members but if no secondary members are available, operations read from the primary.

Btw, I saw some same issues  but all of them still not have a clear solution. :(

We are using:

- mongoose: v4.9.5
- Mongo server: v3.2
- Node: v5.12.0

Comment: You really should only be reading from the "primary" unless you really understand what that means and all the implications. If you have to ask the question, then you should probably stick to reading from the primary. Seems to be the preference settings are working as designed.

Comment: i need to configure to read from `secondary` because of `primary` current full load by `write` operator. if the settings are working as designed so why it read both from `primary` and `secondary`.

Comment: That is not reason enough alone to do this. If your primary is under heavy load then "sharding" is the first place you should be looking. Secondary reads "by design" mean that the data is not guaranteed up to date. Only when you accept that as a given fact your app can live with is it really a valid option. Secondary reads are not for scaling, just as replication does not replace backup.

Comment: yep i got it. It seems `reads from Secondary` is the bad solution for issues primary full loading.

Comment: Hi Huy Tran - can you check your databaseUrl, to make sure that it is specifying the replica set correctly? Perhaps that might be connected with the problem you're seeing?

Comment: I sure my databaseUrl is correct, because when i use setting `readPreference: 'secondary'`, it's work. But the problem is setting readPreference: 'secondaryPreferred'. It's read both from `primary` & `Secondary` while 2 secondaries are alive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people who have same issue,
I confirmed that this behaviour originated from the node driver, which the Python driver and the Java driver doesn't seem to exhibit.
Mongo developer fixed that bug and waiting to merge to master. You can check in this ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-1049